# Excel macro to show all selections of a multi-select listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create an Excel sheet file with a list box with multi selection as :

```
item1 
item2
item3
item4
...
..
```

And then when I select for Example `item1` and `item3` from that listbox the selected items are populated on another cell with display as

```
item1 - item 2  are selected
```

The solution that I tried is creating  multi-select listbox and I attached a macro to it and then I tried to loop on listbox display selected item to a cell but I didn't know to write the Macro, I am not expert on Excel I need to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), In other words we need to see what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: the solution that I tried is creating multi-select listbox and I attached a macro to it and then I tried to loop on listbox display selected item to a cell but i didn't know to write the Macro, I am not expert on Excel I need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Should Work Given you are starting with a Fresh No Items Selected ListBox. I choose to add and remove items from the already made string, instead of looping every object every selection/deselection for performance reason. That is an option but this should run much smoother. But if you already have items selected in your ListBox this won't account for them until you deselect then re-select them.

The other difference between this option and looping all values every time, is that with this method it adds the selections/values in order of when they where selected oppose to in the same order as they are in the ListBox, this could be a positive a negative or indifferent to your purpose but figured I should add that in.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim lngCurrentItem As Long
Dim strCurrentItem As String
Dim strAllSelectedItems As String
Dim rngOutput As Range

Set rngOutput = [J1]
lngCurrentItem = ListBox1.ListIndex

strAllSelectedItems = rngOutput
strAllSelectedItems = Replace(strAllSelectedItems, " Are Selected", "")
strAllSelectedItems = Replace(strAllSelectedItems, " Is Selected", "")

strCurrentItem = ListBox1.List(lngCurrentItem)

If ListBox1.Selected(lngCurrentItem) Then
    If strAllSelectedItems = "No Items Selected" Then
        rngOutput = strCurrentItem & " Is Selected"
    Else
        rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " - " & strCurrentItem & " Are Selected"
    End If
Else
    strAllSelectedItems = Replace(strAllSelectedItems, " - " & strCurrentItem, "")
    strAllSelectedItems = Replace(strAllSelectedItems, strCurrentItem, "")
    If strAllSelectedItems = "" Then
        rngOutput = "No Items Selected"
    ElseIf InStr(1, strAllSelectedItems, " - ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " Are Selected"
    Else
        rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " Is Selected"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

IF you would like to loop the entire list every time (IF you list box is small enough you won't really notice much of a difference in speed, Just make sure your list box isn't set to like an entire Column with over 1 million cells, and you should be fine)

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim lngCurrentItem As Long
Dim strCurrentItem As String
Dim strAllSelectedItems As String
Dim rngOutput As Range

Set rngOutput = [J1]

strAllSelectedItems = ""

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    strCurrentItem = ListBox1.List(i)

    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        If strAllSelectedItems = "" Then
            strAllSelectedItems = strCurrentItem
        Else
            strAllSelectedItems = strAllSelectedItems & " - " & strCurrentItem
        End If
    End If

Next i

If strAllSelectedItems = "" Then
    rngOutput = "No Items Selected"
ElseIf InStr(1, strAllSelectedItems, " - ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " Are Selected"
Else
    rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " Is Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry one more thing I have to assign the macro to the listbox and that's it ?

Comment: @Molwiko YEs and change the *J1* in  `Set rngOutput = [J1]` to the cell address of where you want the output

Comment: My knowledge is limited in VB when I try to run your code it stop in For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1 , I think because the listBox1 it's not the right reference, how to give a name to a listbox and put the right reference in the code ?

Comment: Do you have more then one ListBox in your file? If so you can  Goto the Developer Tab and select Design Mode, While in Design mode click on the list box you want to add the code too, while the listbox is selected the top left of the screen (to the left of the Formula Bar) with have the list boxes name. If that doesn't work, but you can right click on the listbox and the Name `List Box 1` (With the spaces) is in the window it means you have the wrong type of listbox. This code will only work with an ActiveX Control, ***NOT*** with a Form Control.

Comment: Oh, I am working on mac and I have developer tab but I can't find the rest, but I think the issue is I am working on mac